# Can all scions make “the choice” or is it just Changelings?

Tags: the-dresden-files

It’s said that Changelings are apparently just a specific type/subgroup of Scions, which raises the question:

Since changelings can decide to “choose” one side or the other of their heritage (or remain neutral), is there any information/evidence on whether this is in general a capability of all Scions and if other types of them possess that choice too?

Or is that unknown?

Comment: What are all the Scion types you're referring to? Might be too broad if you don't specify.

Comment: @Paul that’s the thing - I was actually wondering if having a choice is meant to be taken as a very broad thing that half-humans/half-something else all possess, or if it’s perhaps stated anywhere to just be a Changeling (fae scion) trait? Hope that makes sense?  I guess if the question is too broad that in itself can be an answer (or I can delete it if it doesn’t reach standards)

Comment: @Paul maybe this will help explain what I mean by scions better than me? The quesion being about these sorts of people: https://dresdenfiles.fandom.com/wiki/Scion

Comment: I'm pretty sure the term is used (and described) the first Bigfoot short story.  I can't look it up at the moment, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jim's actually provided the answer to this one:

> **Does Kincaid have the ability to “choose” like Faerie changelings (i.e Meryl/Fix/Lily)?”**
>
> All scions do, though if they never twig to the fact that they ARE a scion, it’s their actions that make the Choice for them. Kincaid made his Choice a long, long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't say it applies definitely to all Scions, since the term isn't really used in the books and so I don't know for sure whether you only count creatures truly born of two (sharing genetics) races or if you include things like White Court virgins and similar.

If you do, then we know at least the Red Court Infected and White Court Virgins make a choice. Similar is the case with Denarian "infected" (those with a coin and Shadow but who haven't let the demons into their heart).

If you're talking about other things I actually can't think of any half-critters that are not of fae origin that also don't fall into the category idescribed.

That said, a lot of the recent writing in Dresden seems to be around the power of free will and choice, so I expect Jim would write that anything half human comes with the ability to choose baked in.

Comment: Vampires do not really choose, red court infected have to kill to complete the transformation but if they resist the urge to kill they do not turn back.  White court children are kept in the dark about the Hunger until their first feeding so its not really a choice.

Comment: It's only the Wraith children that we see being kept in the dark, there's no reason that the other houses follow the same route.

Comment: @Revenant I agree that it's not precisely the same for all, but from the metaphysical standpoint both vampire types choose to go full monster or not. You're right that in practice it's not quite as clear/clean as the changelings seem to get, but those were the only counter examples I can recall from the books thus far. As for the Raith kids, iirc, the "kept in the dark" thing ended after Lara took over per her agreement with Harry.

Comment: @Paul - I think, given that there are probably many more scions and changelings than we ever guessed (intentionally, like Winters, or strangely, like Goodman Grey), we don't know all the rules.  Choice is definitely a theme in Jim's writing, but the nature of that choice is not always clear to the chooser, and I think pertinent to the question, neither are the results.

Comment: @Radhil I didn't claim that all Scions have a choice, I claimed that if we could half-vamps, we at least have evidence of non-fae Scions that do have one. In fact, my very opening sentence states that.

Comment: In the case of the Red Court infected, you don't choose so much as delay indefinitely. The White Court virgin has an actual "exit" available, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in canon to answer the question at the moment, that being said.

I do not think a changeling is ever referred to as a Scion in universe which leads me to believe the two terms have different meanings a changeling is Mortal/Fae while a Scion is Mortal/Other

If a Scion could choose to become human it would stand to reason they could choose to become the other that their parent was and we see a Scion get killed in Proven Guilty perhaps it happened to fast for a choice to be made but I would lean towards the Scion could not choose.